# DNSCrypt servers and privacy + security

Tags: dns

I'm using open-source router firmware, which also provides my DNS and includes DNSCrypt feature for DNS resolving. As a cyber sec enthusiastic I like this feature, I've been using it for a while and I've tried various free & open DNSCrypt servers.

However, I have to change my DNSCrypt resolver every now and then, because many of them seem to have lots of downtime issues, which naturally affect my network usage. After doing a bit of research, it seems that lots DNSCrypt servers are maintained by individuals, communities and in some cases some companies as well (e.g. Cisco OpenDNS, AdGuard DNS, etc.)

I've been trying to find the most fault-tolerant, free & open DNSCrypt server that would also support DNSSec, with low downtime, no "over paranoid DNS query filtering" (such as with AdGuard) and no logging feature. I've found some, but most of them seem to have downtime problems.

I'm not a DNSCrypt expert and I'm familiar with the basic concept of DNSCrypt only, so my question is that would these open DNSCrypt server providers be able to examine my DNS queries and e.g. trace them back to my public IP? After all, all queries go through their DNSCrypt servers. Or are the queries being encrypted in the DNSCrypt process itself, so that queries cannot be examined in their servers?

Comment: We can't recommend servers, so I removed that part.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on main page of the project:

> DNSCrypt is a protocol that encrypts, authenticates and optionally anonymizes communications between a DNS client and a DNS resolver. It prevents DNS spoofing. It uses cryptographic signatures to verify that responses originate from the chosen DNS resolver and haven’t been tampered with.

So this technology protects the **path** between you and the resolver you chose. However, the resolver can do whatever it wants both inspect the data you sent to it, as well as send you bogus data. This protocol is like a competitor of DoH/DoT, it "just" secures part of the path of the DNS resolution, it is not end to end (whereas on the contrary DNSSEC is end to end but guarantees you only integrity, not confidentiality).

FWIW the gist of the protocol is just the following which can be seen as a lightweight version of TLS:

> Both the client and the resolver initially generate a short-term key
> pair for each supported encryption system.
>
> From a client perspective, a DNSCrypt session begins with the client
> sending a non-authenticated DNS query to a DNSCrypt-enabled resolver.
> This DNS query encodes the certificate versions supported by the
> client, as well as a public identifier of the provider requested by
> the client.
>
> The resolver responds with a public set of signed certificates, that
> must be verified by the client using a previously distributed public
> key, known as the provider public key.

If the client also does not check the server certificate, it is easy to hijack this traffic hence you get full confidentiality... without knowing to whom you exactly are sending the traffic, which is kind of similar to plain text anyway.

Note also how "anonymity" is just a recent option. It uses the classic trick of using a relay: the relay will know your client IP but the real nameserver knows only the IP address of the relay.